# Renting a flat or rooms in the Alps area for winter season

Tags: online-resources, bookings, accommodation, alps, mobile-apps

I'm looking for resources to rent a flat or rooms in the Alps area for a season (4 to 5 months).

By resources I mean:

- Renting websites
- Travel agencies
- Mobile apps
- Forums
- Chat rooms
- Bulletin boards
- Any other mean to get a flat

The obvious answer is Airbnb but I want to look in other places. Sometimes you can find hidden gems for certain subjects...

I'm interested in ski areas like Chamonix or Innsbruck. France, Austria and Italy are OK. Switzerland is probably too expensive generally.

Comment: Which Alps and which country?

Comment: There is no silver bullet, it's actually very difficult. Affordable long term accommodation in sky resorts is far and few between and landlords aren't particularly interested in someone staying for a few months, there is a lot more money to be made in short-term vacation rentals. Many people working the season have to live down in the valley and commute every day.